# FAILURE: Build completed with 10 failures

Tags: android

I just started working on Android and when I tried installing a number of items or packages, I got the following **errors**:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.28.0
```

More errors:

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material3/material3/1.3.2/material3-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material3/material3-window-size-class/1.3.2/material3-window-size-class-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.2
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.ireward:compose-html:1.0.2
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.28.0
         project :app > com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.28.0
         project :app > com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.28.0
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/material/material/1.3.2/material-1.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.9.0
         project :app > io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.9.0 > io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:core:0.9.0
```

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44')
    }
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.2'
        coroutines = '1.6.4'
        accompanist = '0.28.0' // https://github.com/google/accompanist
        datastore = '1.0.0' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore
        navigation = '2.5.3'
        lifecycle = '2.5.1' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle
        material3 = '1.3.2'
        // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3
        work = '2.7.1' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work
        rcview = '1.2.1' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview
        rcview_select = '1.1.0'
        emoji2_version = "1.2.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            excludes += 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'
        }
    }
    kapt {
        useBuildCache = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation "com.github.ireward:compose-html:1.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:106.5249.126'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44.2'

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$datastore"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-core:$datastore"

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.5"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1'

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"

    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1")

    // Work
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work" // optional - GCMNetworkManager support
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work" // optional - Test helpers
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:$work" // optional - Multiprocessor support


    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation"

    // status bar customization
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.28.0'

    // Accompanist
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:$accompanist" // Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:$accompanist" // Pager Indicators
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:$accompanist"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$accompanist"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:$accompanist"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rcview"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$rcview_select"

    // Card view
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    // Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"


    //implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha17'

    // Google Sign In Integration
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"

    // optional - Test helpers for Lifecycle runtime
    testImplementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing:$lifecycle"

    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'

    // https://github.com/Bryanx/themed-toggle-button-group
    implementation "nl.bryanderidder:themed-toggle-button-group:1.4.1"

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"

    implementation 'io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.9.0'

    implementation("androidx.emoji2:emoji2:$emoji2_version")
    implementation("androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views:$emoji2_version")
    implementation("androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:$emoji2_version")
}
```

### I don't know where the problem is.

If, anyone knows exactly where the problem here is, please let me know. I been spending hours through this without knowing where the issues are exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code says it all. 'material3' library is actually on 1.0.1
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

So change the line in `build.gradle`.